# API Issue with Valid Data from CMDATAPI.DataAPI

Tags: c#, okuma

We have an C# application that we created and have been using for a couple of years.
It has an issue that doesn't present dependably, it will show up in testing with PC NC Simulator if we start the simulator and our App in a certain order or it won't if we get that startup order right.
We have not seen the issue in actual machines so after a lot of looking we set the problem asside.

Now we have seen it in an actual VMC machine control, so we need to solve this problem.
Our application poles the Thinc API every 200ms and then sends that data out via Modbus TCP to an external PLC.

Our Thinc App is reading Common Variables and the machine Mode (Auto-Manual-MDI) on every cycle.
The problem we see is that on every other call to the Thinc API results in all 0 values instead of the correct values.  Then the time through the loop it gets good values.

Has anyone seen this and is it an issue with the API or is it our application.  We have gone through our app and can't find any reason for this, unless we are using the API library incorrectly.(looks like the examples)

We are using the v1.17.2 version of the API for backwards compatibility with older machines that haven't been upgraded but we have the same problem with versions of the API as new as v1.21.1 and v1.23.0 .  So I don't think it is API related.

Greg

Comment: It's possible you're attempting to get data too often. When you say you're reading the common vars on "every cycle" Does that mean 200ms or something else? You might need to post the relevant code here in order for anyone to troubleshoot. Or you can email api@okuma.com

Comment: We have tried increasing the time between reads up to 1000ms without any difference.
So every 1000ms we call the API function to get 13 Common Variables and the Machines Mode.  Then we send that data out.  Using the debugger that all appears to take about 1-2 milliseconds.